# Add a parametrised URL to a Lift application

Tags: parameters, url-routing, lift

I need the most basic case of parametrised URLs: having an URL like `localhost:8080/editStudy/4` which will lead to a form for editing the study with an ID equal to 4.

But even after going through the Lift Wiki and the books I have, I didn't find out how to do it. What I have so far is a HTML page `editStudy.html` which will, in future, contain the editing form, a class `StudyDisplayer` which is supposed to render the form, an object `StudyDisplayer` which defines something like a menu (it is a ParamMenuable, whatever this is), and an entry in the sitemap.

When go to `localhost:8080/editStudy/4` I get

> The Requested URL /editStudy/4 was not found on this server

despite the location being referenced in the sitemap. What did I do wrong? Where do I tell Lift to display the editStudy page when the URL is accessed?

---

editStudy.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="litsuche.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <span data-lift="Menu.builder"></span>
    </nav>
    <div data-lift="StudyDisplayer">
        <h1>Editing the study <span id="reference"></span></h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

StudyDisplayer:

```
package code
package snippet

import org.rumtscho.litsuche._
import net.liftweb.util.BindHelpers._
import xml.Text

import net.liftweb.sitemap._

object StudyDisplayer {

  def showStudies = {
    val theStudies = Study.findAll

    "li *" #> theStudies.map {
      s =>
        ".id *" #> Text(s.id.toString) &
        ".handmadeRef *" #> Text(s.reference) & 
        ".description *" #> Text(s.description) & 
        ".editStudyButton" #> <button class="editStudyButton" onclick={"location.href='" + editStudyLoc.calcHref(s) + "'"}>edit</button>
    }
  }


    val editStudyLoc = Menu.param[Study](
        "EditStudy", 
        "editStudy", //This is supposed to be some kind of link, but it doesn't work with the name of the file, with or without a .html ending. The file itself is in the root directory. 
        Study.findByIdAsString(_),
        _.id.toString()
        ) / "editStudy" / *
}

class StudyDisplayer(study: Study) {
  def render = "#reference *" #> study.reference
}
```

And the relevant excerpt from Boot.scala:

```
def sitemap(): SiteMap = SiteMap(
  Menu.i("Home") / "index",
  Menu.i("List studies") / "studies", 
  Menu(StudyDisplayer.editStudyLoc),
  Menu.i("Temporary page") / "scratchpad")

LiftRules.setSiteMap(sitemap())
```

Comment: Beside the usual sources (Wiki, Simply Lift), I also found http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2009/09/understanding-lifts-sitemap/. It says that the Link parameter is simply a link. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Can you try specifying the path simply as `/ "editStudy"` (without the trailing `/ *`)?

Comment: @jcern when I remove the trailing / *, I get "no navigation defined" instead of the navigation menu on other pages calling Menu.builder, and the same error when calling /editStudy/4.

Comment: I'd put some logging in `Study.findByIdAsString`.  The parser needs to return a Full[Study] in order for the URL to match, otherwise you'll get a 404.  Adding some logging will let you know 1. Is the parser getting called and 2. Is it returning Empty or Failure instead of what you expect?

Comment: @jcern I realized that I had added the file as a simple menu item too, to make sure there's nothing wrong with it. Once I removed the simple item *and* the trailing `/ *`, it worked. So please write a full answer so I can accept it. It would be nice if you could also say something more about how Lift matches the URL, or where to read about it. I was going by Simply Lift, and section 6.3 literally says "Finally, the URL is defined by / "item" / * which is pretty much what it looks like. It’ll match an incoming request of the form /item/xxx and xxx".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lift has two mechanisms for adding parameters. [`Menu.param`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/sitemap/Menu.scala#L567) and [`Menu.params`](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/sitemap/Menu.scala#L571). The difference between them is the number of parameters that are required.

Menu.param assumes a single parameter, so in your case you had:

```
Menu.param[Study](
    "EditStudy", 
    "editStudy", 
    Study.findByIdAsString(_),
    _.id.toString()
) / "editStudy"
```

This is the simplest mechanism, as it looks for a template called "editStudy.html" and takes the one parameter it assumes exists and passed it to your function: `Study.findIdAsString`. If the function returns `Full`, the unboxed value will be passed to your snippet for rendering. If the function returns `Empty` Lift will return a 404 by default.

Menu.Params is a more or less the same idea, but it allows you to specify multiple parameter and/or match multiple URLs. For example, we could adapt your example to be:

```
Menu.params[Study]("EditStudy", "EditStudy", {
    case s :: Nil => Study.findByIdAsString(s)
    case _ => Empty
}, {
    case g = > g.id :: Nil
}) / "editStudy" / *
```

You'll notice here we have a wildcard match after "editStudy". The reason is there is no assumption on the number of parameters so you need to specify what it is looking for `*` if you are looking for a single parameter or `**` to match every subpath to "editStudy". For every pattern you want to look for, you would just add a new case statement to your match.

You can even type `Menu.params` with a tuple if you want to return multiple items, for example:

```
Menu.param[(Study, Grade)]("EditStudy", "EditStudy", {
    case s :: g :: Nil => (Study.findByIdAsString(s), Grade.findByIdAsString(g))
    case _ => Empty
}, {
    case (g, s) => g.id :: s.id :: Nil
}) / "editStudy" / **
```

Which would look for two id parameters in the url like: "/editStudy/1234/5678"

Also note, when dealing with pattern matching it is often cleaner to use extractors for retrieving values. [This article](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) has some more info on them if you need it.